# Real Analysis: Proof of Radius of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, solution-verification

[image]

I just would like to know are my steps right.

$\textbf{I needed to show that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is the same a that of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nz^n$.}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the root test ($\sqrt[n]{n}$ tends to 1).

Comment: Yes, I have proven $\lim_{\ n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Does that allow me to say $\lim_{\ n\to\infty}\sup(n^{\frac{1}{n}}(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}) \to \alpha$ without this separation?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "weird separation".  Also, your parentheses are not balanced.

Comment: Sorry about that. But I have a proof clipped to this question. I wanted to know if it was the correct way to do it.

Comment: You need to point out that the limsup of $n^{1/n}$ is actually a limit rather than a limsup.  Otherwise the argument is flawed because the limsup of the product may not be the product of limsups.

Comment: Okay and that is true because we've also shown that if $\lim x_n$ exists then the $\lim \ \sup x_n = \lim \ \inf x_n = \lim \ x_n.$ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that your notation $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup$ is a bit unusual.  I would use the traditinal "limsup" so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: ok, thanks I really appreciate the help